# "this" of a function in React Component- Please read lines at the end of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class MyButton extends Component {

    state = { tapped: false }
    tap() {
          this.setState({ tapped: true });  // --> 'this' here is undefined 
    }
    render() {
        return (
             <button onClick={ this.tap }>TAP ME</button>
        )
    }
}
```

I know with ES6 class React doesn't auto bind this to component's instance, hence inside tap "this" is undefined. What I don't understand here is why tap function is present in the component's instance and is not throwing an error undefined of tap doesn't exist? How tap is part of component instance?

Comment: It clearly gives an undefined error for me:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9oyll1j02r

Comment: Downvoted because the code is throwing an undefined.

Comment: I know inside the function it will be undefined. I want to know why this.tap is Component.tap not undefined.tap. The correct function in the component instance is being called with this.tap

Comment: @AkashVerma Are you asking "Why `this` is not undefined at `onClick={ this.tap }` ??

Comment: @Prakashsharma yes.

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyButton extends Component {

    state = { tapped: false }

    tap = () => {
          this.setState({ tapped: true }); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <button onClick={ this.tap }>TAP ME</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but be cautious about using arrow fns in components if there will be a "lot" of them since they're duplicated across instances. That's one reason why people bind them in the ctor.

Comment: Yes you are right about that. I prefer SFCs anyway